# MigLayout: how to change default “related” and “unrelated” gap values?

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

It is a nice feature to use “related” and “unrelated” gap values in the MigLayout container, but I would like to change their default values. How to do that? I don’t like to use explicit numbers, e.g. “wrap 15px”.  “wrap related” is more flexible and readable.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the class PlatformDefaults: it has api to customize (nearly) all semantically known unitValues, f.i. to set the unrelated gap for both x/y

```
UnitValue myGap = new UnitValue(15, UnitValue.LPX, null);
PlatformDefaults.setUnrelatedGap(myGap, myGap);
```

Beware, though: the default values are those which the per-OS guidelines require, if you change them your ui will violate those guidelines!